# How to display only the key from the bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with millions of documents. Suppose each of my documents has some code, and I need to find the list of codes matching some criteria. The only way I found doing that, is using whole lot of aggregations, so I created an ugly query which does exactly what I want:

```
POST my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
  "range": {
    "timestamp": {
      "gte": "2017-08-01T00:00:00.000",
      "lt": "2017-08-08T00:00:00.000"
    }
  }
},
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"codes": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "code",
    "size": 10000
  },
  "aggs": {
    "days": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "day",
        "format": "dd"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hours": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "hour",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd:HH"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "hour_income": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "max_income": {
          "max_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "hours>hour_income"
          }
        },
        "day_income": {
          "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "hours.hour_income"
          }
        },
        "more_than_sixty_percent": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "dayIncome": "day_income",
              "maxIncome": "max_income"
            },
            "script": "params.maxIncome - params.dayIncome * 60 / 100 > 0 ? 1 : 0"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "amount_of_days": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "days.more_than_sixty_percent"
      }
    },
    "bucket_filter": {
      "bucket_selector": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "amountOfDays": "amount_of_days"
        },
        "script": "params.amountOfDays >= 3"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

The response I get is a few millions lines of JSON, consisting of buckets. Each bucket has more than 700 lines (and buckets of its own), but all I need is its key, so that I have my list of codes. I guess it's not good having a response a few thousand times larger than neccessary, and there might be problems with parsing. So I wanted to ask, is there any way to hide the other info in the bucket and get only the keys?

Thanks.